# "Table not found" exception with hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I'm getting the following exception with hibernate:

```
10:18:14,795 INFO  [SchemaValidator] Running schema validator

10:18:14,795 INFO  [SchemaValidator] fetching database metadata

10:18:16,958 INFO  [DatabaseMetadata] table not found: DUMMY_TABLE

10:18:16,963 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=bkoMdw-ear.ear/bkoMdw-ejb.jar#bkoMdw state=Create
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: bkoMdw] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory

(...)

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: DUMMY_TABLE
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1127)
     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:359)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
     at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
     at 

org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
```

The problem is that the table exists and the datasource file is correctly configured.

What I'm missing? Any advise to troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you **think** the table exists and that the datasource is correctly configured while Hibernate **knows** that this isn't correct.

Increase the log levels and use `-Dhibernate.show_sql=true` to enable logging for SQL statements. That should help to track this one down.

**[EDIT]** Also make sure you don't have white space before or after a `@Table` annotation. If you have this annotation:

```
@Table(name = "myTable ") // Note the space after the name!!
```

Then Hibernate will use the quoted name to create the table (so you will have a table with the SQL name `'MYTABLE '`) but it won't always quote the name when you run queries.

Comment: The output from hibernate doens't show table names with whitespaces. They should add some brackets or something

Comment: @Tommey: File a bug report, please

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with a view I used in my mapping. After I've disabled Hibernate's validation, it works correctly. Seems, that the validation has a problem with views.

Comment: Funny, I get `table not found` for actual tables, but views works.

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure the case is correct. You might have it in the databse as dummy_table may be.

Comment: My table name and entity's name mismatched. Bad spellings. Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem. Someone put @Table(name = "myTable ") on an entity and Hiberante creates the table. When Hibernate then checks to see if the table exists it probably trims the table name and gives you the error.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me when I changed 
@Table(name = "schema.table")
To
@Table(name = "table", schema = "schema")

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with a mysql database.
The issue was that I used Upper case names for tables.
I lowered them down and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with postgresql and hibernate 5.2.10.

The table definitely existed. When I turned validate off, everything worked. It turned out that the table could probably not be found because hibernate could not handle no specified schema. It seemed related to: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11286.

**I updated postgresql and the dialect (PostgreSQLXXDialect).** The problem went away after that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, case sensitivity was important. While declaring table='DUMMY_TABLE' in hibernate mapping was completely working on Windows machine, it did not work after moving mysql server to linux system. I had to change all uppercase letters to lower cases such as table='dummy_table'

Answer (score 0):

@Hendrik has the right idea. I had the same problem and I was able to fix the issue by adding the beans bellow to my applicaiton context file.

```
<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConfig" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseConfigBean">
    <property name="caseSensitiveTableNames" value="false"/>
    <property name="qualifiedTableNames" value="true"/>
    <property name="datatypeFactory">
        <bean class="org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlDataTypeFactory"/>
    </property>
    <property name="metadataHandler">
        <bean class="org.dbunit.ext.mysql.MySqlMetadataHandler"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dbUnitDatabaseConnection" class="com.github.springtestdbunit.bean.DatabaseDataSourceConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="databaseConfig" ref="dbUnitDatabaseConfig"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="transactionAware" value="true"/>
    <property name="schema" value="yourSchemaName"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception from hibernate. 
In my case, it was because the database user was not properly authorized to see the tables. The tables were definitively there on the database.

After I assigned the roles *db_datareader* to the user for this database it worked.

However, in another case, where the tables weren't actually there, I got exactly the same exception from hibernate. I cases where the tables are there, I think hibernate might show no more information because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I am using flyway db migration and for oracle, because of a single user, single schema limitation, I had to force my all microservices to use the same schema.
Surprisingly few microservices was able to read the common table loading from the dependent library but one service which was getting created by Kubernetes deployment in between was failing with this error.

Below setting helped to fix it:

Set ddl-auto=none

```
# JPA Configuration
  jpa:
    database-platform: ${DB_DIALECT:org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect}
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was getting this error after renaming my table, but it was still saying:

> Missing table: OLD_NAME

even though I was certain I'd updated all the references.

It turns out I had to do a Maven Clean in Eclipse, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using H2. I had a column that was a reserved word (See [H2 reserved words](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords))

It was really frustrating as no error messages would be kicked out. The sql debugging showed the table was being created.